# Como usar o Files.move com o Java?

Tags: java, java-ee, spring

Criei um upload de fotos no meu sistema, essa fotos sao guardadas em um temp , preciso move-las para um diretorio padrao, sem ser o temp.

Esse e o metodo que cria o diretorio :

```
public FotoStorageLocal() {
    //Versao MAC
    //this(getDefault().getPath(System.getenv("user.home"), ".genesisfotos"));

    // versao windows
    this(getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".genesisfotos"));
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>> CRIADO GENESIS + FOTOS ");
}

public FotoStorageLocal(Path path) {
    this.local = path;
    criarPastas();
}
```

E esse e o metodo que que faz a foto ser salva e depois transferia da pasta temp para o diretorio padrao.

Eu rodo o sistema mas ele nao consegue tirar a foto da pasta tem para outra pasta, segue codigo

```
public void salvar(String foto) {
    try {
        Files.move(this.localTemporario.resolve(foto), this.local.resolve(foto));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro movendo a foto para destino final", e);
    }
    try {
        Thumbnails.of(this.local.resolve(foto).toString()).size(40, 68).toFiles(Rename.PREFIX_DOT_THUMBNAIL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro gerando thumbnail", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O uso do método `Files.move()` é:

```
Path sourcePath      = Paths.get("data/logging-copy.properties");
Path destinationPath = Paths.get("data/subdir/logging-moved.properties");

try {
    Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath,
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note que são utilizados como parâmetros `(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`.
Certifique de que o método `Files.move(this.localTemporario.resolve(foto), this.local.resolve(foto));` esteja usando corretamente o método

Comment: Boa noite gaspar, antes de mais nada obrigado pela atenção, fiz as alteracao mas mesmo assim nao consigo mover o arquivo do temp para o diretorio acima, vou colocar a classe no pastebin pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sim, coloque o código editando a pergunta ou cole o link no comentário por favor.

Comment: Segue o codigo Gaspar - https://pastebin.com/XzJVsj5y

Comment: Tente colocando o código na linha 53:
`Path sourcePath = localTemporario.resolve(foto);
Path destinationPath = local.resolve(foto);
Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: Tentei o que me indicou mas mesmo assim a foto continua apenas no temp, ela nao sobre um diretorio, as imagens continuam apenas na temp, as pastas estao assim: C:\Users\BRUNO\.genesisfotos\temp, o certo seria voltar  um diretorio : C:\Users\BRUNO\.genesisfotos\

Comment: Gaspar consegui resolver o erro, estava faltando no metodo salvar um parametro, muito obrigado pela ajuda , funciono com suas dicas.

Comment: Valeu @Brunexx! Fico contente em ajudar